# React App Server Side Routing - API Call

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a react app using create-react-app. The app is almost complete. But now I need to add SSR to this. (Maybe not exactly SSR, but just to make sure that server responds correctly if the user hits the url). I read that one solution for this is to send index.html for any request that matches /app*. I did that, but here is the problem:

The subsequent routes are dependent on the data retrieved on the previous page. For ex - if I have 2 nested routes /app/abc & /app/abc/def, the data for component rendered for 'def' is dependent on the data retrieved at 'abc'. So, when a user hits enter on '/app/abc/def', the data does not get loaded.

How can I handle this ? Please point me to any resource if possible.

Comment: Please add relevant code to the question.

Comment: Try to use asynch false in your server request.

Comment: @MukulSharma could you please elaborate ?